# How should I integrate $\int _{ 0 }^{ \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} } \frac { dx }{ (1+x^2)\sqrt{1-x^2}\ } $?

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

How should I integrate $\int _{ 0 }^{ \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} } \frac { dx }{ (1+x^2)\sqrt{1-x^2}\ } $ ?

I tried substituting $x=1/t$,but it is not working.Could someone help?Thanks.

Comment: Try $x=\cos t$.

Comment: Does this help: Try  $x = \sqrt{\cos(2\theta)}$ then you have $1-x^{2}= 1-\cos(2\theta)=2 \sin^{2}\theta$ and $1+x^{2} = 2\cos^{2}\theta$??

Comment: For other alternatives, see http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1505148/find-the-indefinite-integral-int-dx-over-1x2-sqrt1-x2/1505197#1505197

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $x=\sin \theta$ and then
\begin{eqnarray}
\int _{ 0 }^{ \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} } \frac { dx }{ (1+x^2)\sqrt{1-x^2}\ }&=&\int _{ 0 }^{ \arcsin\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} } \frac {d\theta }{1+\sin^2\theta}\\
&=&\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}\arctan(\sqrt{2}\tan\theta)\bigg|_{ 0 }^{\arcsin\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}}\\
&=&\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}\arctan(\sqrt{2}\cdot\frac{1}{\sqrt2})\\
&=&\frac{\pi}{4\sqrt 2}.
\end{eqnarray}
Here $\arctan(\arcsin\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}})=\frac{1}{\sqrt2}$ and
$$ \int\frac{1}{1+\sin^2\theta}d\theta=\int\frac{1}{1+2\tan^2\theta}d\tan\theta=\frac{1}{\sqrt2}\arctan(\sqrt2\tan\theta)+c.$$