# Solving $\int {dx\over(1+x^2)\sqrt{1-(\arctan x)^2}}$

Tags: integration

> $$\int {dx\over (1+x^2)\sqrt{1-(\arctan x)^2}}$$

I found a [similar answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1505148/find-the-indefinite-integral-int-dx-over-1x2-sqrt1-x2) but did not manage to use it in this case

I can see the function $\arcsin x'$ and $\arctan x'$ in the expression.

Comment: $\arctan (x^{2})$ or $(\arctan (x))^{2}$?

Comment: @Albert (arctanx)^2

Comment: $\int {dx\over(1+x^2)\sqrt{1-(arctan x)^2}}$ or $\int {dx\over1+(x^2)\sqrt{1-(arctan x)^2}}$?

Comment: $\arcsin(\arctan(x)) + c$

Comment: Did you try $u=\arctan(x)$?

Comment: @Albert the second

Comment: So, it is interesting. Please edit your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\int\frac{1}{\left(1+x^2\right)\sqrt{1-\arctan^2(x)}}\space\text{d}x=$$
$$\int\frac{1}{\left(1+x^2\right)\sqrt{1-\left(\arctan(x)\right)^2}}\space\text{d}x=$$

---

Substitute $u=\arctan(x)$ and $\text{d}u=\frac{1}{x^2+1}\space\text{d}x$:

---

$$\int\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-u^2}}\space\text{d}u=$$
$$\arcsin\left(u\right)+\text{C}=$$
$$\arcsin\left(\arctan(x)\right)+\text{C}$$

Comment: Did you mean after the arctan sub $$\int\frac{du}{\sqrt{1-u^2}}?$$

Answer (score 4):

Set $\arctan(x) = t$. We then have $\tan(t) = x \implies dx = \sec^2(t)dt$. Hence, the integral becomes
\begin{align}
\int \dfrac{dx}{(1+x^2)\sqrt{(1-(\arctan(x))^2)}} & = \int \dfrac{dt}{\sqrt{1-t^2}} = \arcsin(t) + \text{const} = \arcsin\left(\arctan(x)\right) + \text{const}
\end{align}

Comment: What do I do with  sec?

Comment: @gbox It gets cancelled off with the $1+\tan^2(t)$ in the denominator.

Comment: In other words $dx/(1+x^2)=d\arctan x$.

Answer (score 1):

Notice, $$\int \frac{dx}{(1+x^2)\sqrt{1-(\tan^{-1}(x))^2}}$$$$=\int \frac{\frac{dx}{1+x^2}}{\sqrt{1-(\tan^{-1}(x))^2}}$$$$=\int \frac{d(\tan^{-1}(x))}{\sqrt{1-(\tan^{-1}(x))^2}}$$$$=\sin^{-1}(\tan^{-1}(x))+C$$

Answer (score 1):

> **Hint #1:** *Substitution*: $$u=\arctan x$$
>
> $$du=\frac{1}{1+x^2}dx$$
>
> **Hint #2:** *Derivative of arcsinx*: $$\frac{d}{du}arcsin u=\frac{1}{\sqrt {1-u^2}}$$